# Saving a webform programmatically in a custom webform handler throws "Entity validation was skipped."

Tags: 8, webforms

I am trying to save a webform submission inside the postSave in a `CustomWebformHandler` class.

```
class CustomWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {
[..]
     public function postSave(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission, $update = TRUE) {
        $data = $webform_submission->getData();
        $data['ssa_attachment'] = $doc_id; //doc_id is retrieved with a query
        $webform_submission->setData($data);
        $webform_submission->set('in_draft', TRUE);
        $webform_submission->save();
     }
}
```

I get the following exception.

> Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: "Entity validation was skipped."

I tried to validate before saving and I get this exception.

> Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction: SELECT w.next_serial AS next_serial\nFROM\n{webform} w\nWHERE webform_id = :db_condition_placeholder_0 FOR UPDATE;

How can I trigger the validation before saving?

Comment: "I am trying to save a webform submission inside the postSave ..." - regardless of validation, I don't know if this is even the question you want to be answered, you can't save the same entity in an postSave event, this causes all kind of errors because you invoke the same event again.

Comment: @Jdrupal, yes, postSave() is for things like invalidating cache tags or you can even modify other entities, but you shouldn't save the same entity again `$webform_submission->save()`, which leads to a stack overflow if no other random error occurs first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [WebformSubmission::resave()](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/blob/8.x-5.x/src/WebformSubmissionInterface.php#L432) method prevents the `::save` and `::postSave` recursion issue from occuring.